# Is there a way to detect if a website is using SPDY?

Tags: http, google-chrome, spdy

Is there a way to detect if a website is communicating with Chrome using SPDY?

Comment: You can use http://spdycheck.org to check SPDY support.

Answer (score 44):

You can view your active SPDY sessions in a current build of Chrome by pulling up:

```
chrome://net-internals/#spdy
```

Comment: Is there something similar to this for Firefox (without using an extension)?

Answer (score 26):

Mike Belshe said

> Yes, indeed SPDY is enabled in Chrome
>   and on Google servers for all SSL 
>   traffic at this point.  (Actually, we
>   do 90% on SPDY, with a 10% holdback 
>   for purposes of A/B comparisons).

http://groups.google.com/group/spdy-dev/browse_thread/thread/4c2396ecbc36b1c4

Answer (score 18):

chrome://net-internals/#spdy to see active SPDY sessions

- Google services run over SPDY (search, gmail, etc)
- F5 [announced SPDY support](http://searchenterprisewan.techtarget.com/news/2240149781/Interop-2012-Mobile-application-delivery-improved-with-SPDY-protocol) on their appliances at Interop 2012
- Akamai announced technical preview for SPDY at Velocity 2012 (June 2012)
- Cloudflare announced SPDY beta for their customers (June 2012)
- As of early March 2012, twitter.com is running SPDY
- There are a few specialized CDN's which have SPDY enabled
- Nginx supports SPDY ([draft 2](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-devel/2012-June/002343.html))
- Apache has a great [mod_spdy](http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/) module

Comment: Opera Turbo uses SPDY as well.

Answer (score 10):

On a couple of SPDY sites I checked, there appear to be these additional request headers that don't appear on standard HTTPS requests.  That might indicate the use of SPDY without requiring a browser extension.

```
:host:     yump.com.au
:method:   GET
:path:     /
:scheme:   https
:version:  HTTP/1.1
```

[image]

You'll also notice that all the request and response header variables are in lowercase (is that part of the SPDY protocol?).

Comment: You are ABSOLUTELY right. The spdy protocol draft 3.1 (link below) even talks about this in section 5.2. 

Thx for noticing this. I was going crazy trying figure this out. I need to do this because i want to use a performance testing tool (such as jmeter or loadrunner) instead of a browser to access a SPDY enabled server.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft3-1

Answer (score 7):

46.5% of browser traffic now supports SPDY (see http://caniuse.com/spdy ), so almost half the users that hit google, twitter or other SPDY enabled websites are already using SPDY.

If you want to get similar gains for your website, then use jetty (7, 8, and 9 all have SPDY support).

Answer (score 4):

Chrome has a plugin to show you which sites are SPDY enabled.
http://www.devthought.com/2012/03/10/chrome-spdy-indicator/

Comment: There is a similar plugin for firefox too: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/spdy-indicator/

Answer (score 2):

Jetty Servlet engine also got decent spdy support. It's completely transparent for the web developer and just needs to be enabled on the server config:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/SPDY

Answer (score 2):

- The website http://spdycheck.org/ checks if SPDY is enabled on a website.
- The Google Chrome extension will tell you with a green icon in the url bar. (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin?hl=en)
- There is also website https://isspdyenabled.com/ to tell you if your browser is supporting SPDY
- You can use Chrome Flags to see more details information visit chrome://net-internals/#spdy in chrome

SPDY is enabled by lots of the major websites: Google, Twitter, Facebook etc

With IE11 supporting SPDY the future looks SPDY... :-D

Answer (score 1):

From the major sites, SPDY is served on all Google products, Twitter, Wordpress.com, TechCrunch.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Kindle Fire may be using SPDY for HTTP traffic through their Silk proxy.  This is based on Amazon's public job posting: http://aws.amazon.com/amazonsilk-jobs/ and is not verified or confirmed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable network.http.spdy.enabled in Firefox 11's about:config and add this extension:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/spdy-indicator/

Answer (score 0):

Try WAPPALYZER,

They provide addon for both Mozilla & chrome browser.
It can identify everything about any website like, server technology, server scripting language, client side scripting language, site using plugins & all major things from most of the websites.

https://wappalyzer.com/download

Answer (score -4):

I doubt that it's used, as the current Chrome/Chromium only supports SPDY detection using the SSL NPN extension, which was only recently added to the edge openssl. And the Alternate-Protocol which is not npn is not supported.
http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft2#TOC-Server-Advertisement-of-SPDY-throug

Update: While this answer was correct in 2010, when it was written, in 2014 it's quite a different story.

Answer (score -6):

Just sniff the TCP/IP packagees from and to the webserver, and check where they are SPDY packages or just HTTP.

Comment: As Google is author of SPDY and Chrome was first browser implementing SPDY on client I have to down vote your answer.

Comment: This is a 4 year old answer. I'll update it. But I'm not sure if downvoting is the right way to make the answer's author update it.